# Android GPS/LapTimer Idea - Do you think it's accurate enough for this?

Tags: android, gps

So I ride Motocross when I'm not programming and was thinking about making an app that can log lap times via Android's GPS(mark a finish line via GPS and everytime you pass this point it records the lap time). Initially I didn't think the GPS was nearly accurate enough to log times within tenths of a second, especially from what I've been reading online but then I took a look at the Android Market and there are some apps that have some rave reviews,TrackMaster being one of them. People are saying that it's quite accurate and I feel like taking on a new project for practice with Android Development...

Do you think they are as accurate as people are claiming?

I realize this is sorta vague but seeing if anyone can lead me in the right direction here..

Jimmy

Answer (score 1):

1hz GPS (what is in most phones) can be accurate, but it depends on your application.

If I'm at 100m at 5s and 250m at 6s, then I'm going really fast.  If there's a finish line at 175m, then you could interpolate and say I crossed it at 5.5s.  And you'd be correct, if you assume I'm not accelerating.  A rapidly-accelerating vehicle may have crossed it at like 5.8s, while a decelerating vehicle may have crossed at 5.2s.

Essentially, the accuracy comes down to the magnitude of your acceleration over the time period.  The amount of error will be proportional to your acceleration.  In a racing application, you can probably assume that the vehicle will be doing the same thing (braking/accelerating) each time it crosses the same point, and so although you may have error, the error should be about the same each lap, which allows for lap-to-lap comparison.

Additionally, if you encourage your users to set their start/finish lines at points where they aren't accelerating much, like at the end of a straight, then they'll have almost no error.

I'm the author of WifiLapper (as well as a palmpilot GPS laptiming app I wrote previously), and I've found while racing that it is accurate to about 1/3rd of a second when running with a 1hz GPS, when compared with the transponder the racing orgs give us.  Part of that may just be because WifiLapper's start/finish line will be offset a bit from where the transponder pickup is.  Personally, I recommend picking up a bluetooth GPS like the 10hz QStarz unit that we use while racing, and then even the uninterpolated results will be accurate within 1/10th.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, GPS is accurate to within 3 - 15 meters. So I feel like that's not quite enough to accurately get tenths of a second.

Comment: Okay.. what about the frequency of updates? I know you can set the requestLocationUpdates parameter to 0. So frequency isn't an issue with the timing correct? Just whether or not the location that is received and trips the "lap" is actually accurate to where you really are?

Comment: From what I've read, getting an accurate location is not as easy as it seems. It doesn't "stream" a constant gps position, so the frequency may not be what you expect it to be. I'd suggest reading http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html#BestPerformance .